# Autocomplete TextView giving wrong output in android

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Hi in the below code I have implemented an autocomplete TextView. If the user selects some account name, I am printing the ID. But every time it is giving me the same account name and account ID. Suppose based on account name account ID I should pass to server. Expected ID is not coming after selecting the account name.

Can any one help me where I did the mistake?

java:

```
 private void fetchAccountJSON() {
    
            autoaccount_name.setHint(Html.fromHtml("Account Name" + " " + "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "* " + "</font>"));
    
    
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Write code for your refresh logic
    
                    sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
                    String operation = "query";
                    String query = "select  *  from Accounts";
                    final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);
                    /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
                    Call<UserAccountQuery> call = service.UserAccountRecordDetails(operation, sessionId, query);
                    /**Log the URL called*/
                    Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAccountQuery>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<UserAccountQuery> call, Response<UserAccountQuery> response) {
                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                                UserAccountQuery userAccountQuery = response.body();
    
                                Gson g = new Gson();
                                String jsonAccount = g.toJson(userAccountQuery);
                                tinydb.putString("jsonAccount", jsonAccount);
                                workingOnResponseAccount(userAccountQuery);
    
                            }
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<UserAccountQuery> call, Throwable t) {
    
                        }
                        //     progressDialog.dismiss();
                    });
                }
            }, 0);
            return;
        }
    
        private void workingOnResponseAccount(UserAccountQuery userAccountQuery) {
    autoaccount_name.setHint(Html.fromHtml("Account Name" + " " + "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "* " + "</font>"));
    String success = userAccountQuery.getSuccess();
    if (success.equals("true")) {
        Results_AccountQ results = userAccountQuery.getResult();
        // records = results.getRecords();
        recordsAccounts = results.getRecordsAccounts();
        for (final RecordsAccounts recordsAccounts1 : recordsAccounts) {
            account_id = recordsAccounts1.getId();
            accountnames = recordsAccounts1.getAccountname();
            final RecordsAccounts recordsAccounts = new RecordsAccounts(account_id, accountnames);
            recordsListAccount.add(recordsAccounts);
            account_name.add(accountnames);
        }
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, account_name);
        autoaccount_name.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoaccount_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String account_namess = adapter.getItem(position);
                boolean isaccount=false;
                for (RecordsAccounts recordsAccounts : recordsListAccount) {
                    if(!isaccount && recordsAccounts.getAccountname().equals(account_namess)){
                        isaccount=true;
                        account_id = recordsAccounts.getId();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected : " + account_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("account_id", account_id);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "records": [
            {
                "accountname": "Cumbum United Scan",
                "industry": "Proprietor",
                "rating": "Diagnostic Center",
                "assigned_user_id": {
                    "value": "19x310",
                    "label": "Pasupathy S"
                },
                "id": "11x1154",
                "starred": "",
                "account_id": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                },
                "modifiedby": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                },
                "bill_pobox": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                },
                "ship_pobox": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "accountname": "Aishwarya Fertility Centre",
                "industry": "Proprietor",
                "rating": "Hospital",
                "assigned_user_id": {
                    "value": "19x310",
                    "label": "Pasupathy S"
                },
                "id": "11x1158",
                "starred": "",
                "account_id": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                },
                "modifiedby": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                },
                "bill_pobox": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                },
                "ship_pobox": {
                    "value": null,
                    "label": ""
                }
            }
            ]
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
for (RecordsAccounts recordsAccounts : recordsListAccount) {
    if(recordsAccounts.getAccountname().equals(account_namess)) //<--
        isaccount=true;   //<--
    account_id = recordsAccounts.getId();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected : " + account_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("account_id", account_id);
}
```

The condition `if(recordsAccounts.getAccountname().equals(account_namess))` just set the `isaccount`. The `account_id = recordsAccounts.getId();` is **always** executed for the items.

Use something like:

```
for (RecordsAccounts recordsAccounts : recordsListAccount) {
   if(!isaccount && recordsAccounts.getAccountname().equals(account_namess)){
        isaccount=true;
        account_id = recordsAccounts.getId();
   }
}
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected : " + account_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.e("account_id", account_id);
```

Comment: No it is not working toast message is not displaying

Comment: @jyothichandra Debug your code. The line `Toast.makeTetx...` is outside any cycle and if condition. In any case, your issue is described in the answer. The `account_id` runs for all the items. You are always using the last item id.